# how to put reactions on several lines and adjust them in CHEMFIG?

Tags: chemfig

How to adjust several reactions vertically on top of each other in CHEMFIG?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting vertically, one over the other, several reactions is not easy in CHEMFIG. Using "invisible arrows" is a difficult option to adjust correctly, especially if multiple lines are required.

One way I found to do this is to place the reactions inside a table using the "tabularx" environment. Each line must contain a complete reaction scheme. Empty lines can be used to insert vertical spaces between reactions. See a general model below:

```
\begin{tabularx}{265pt}{l}
<text> \\
\\
\schemestart <reaction 1> \schemestop \\
\\
\schemestart <reaction 1> \schemestop \\
\end{tabularx}
```

%-------------------------------------------------------
% complete schema
%----------------------------------------------------------

```
\documentclass[margin={1mm 1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setatomsep{1.8em}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}% per right to e left to
\tikzset{myedge/.style={->, -{Latex[#1]}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{265pt}{l}
%
\textbf{Step 1: generation of radicals}
\\
\\
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{R@b\lewis{2:6:,O}-[@a]-[@c]@d\lewis{2:6:,O}H}
%
\arrow{->[$h\nu$ (light) \quad or \quad $\triangle$ (heat)]}[0,3]
%
\chemnameinit{2pt}
\chemname{\chemfig{2\, \, R\lewis{0.2:6:,O}}}{}
%
\chemmove{
    \draw[myedge={right},red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=0pt](a).. controls +(90:4mm) and +(40:4mm)..(b);
    \draw[myedge={left},red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=0pt](c).. controls +(90:4mm) and +(140:4mm)..(d);
}
\schemestop
\\
\\
%---------------------------------------------------
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{R-[0,1.5]\lewis{0.2:6:,O}\hspace{2pt}@e}
%
\chemfig{+\hspace{12pt}@f\hspace{12pt}}
%
\chemfig{H-[@g]-[@h]@i\lewis{0:2:6:,Br}}
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemfig{R-[0,1.5]\lewis{2:6:,O}H}
%
\+
%
\chemfig{\lewis{0.2:4:6:,Br}}
%
\chemmove{
    \draw[myedge={left},red,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=1pt](e.0).. controls +(90:8mm) and +(120:8mm)..(f);
    \draw[myedge={right},red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](g).. controls +(90:8mm) and +(60:8mm)..(f);
    \draw[myedge={left},red,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=1pt](h).. controls +(100:4mm) and +(140:6mm)..(i);
}
\schemestop
\\
%-----------------------------------------------------
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

%-----------------------------------------------------------
The result is:

[image]

If it seems easy to adjust the reactions using "invisible arrows", try this with many lines. ( 9 lines)

[image]

You can also do this:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to use a floating environment in standalone?

Comment: I can do more with "tabularx" than with "align *".

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `\noindent` or `align` inside of `fleqn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}% per right to e left to
\tikzset{myedge/.style={->, -{Latex[#1]}}}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{Step 1: generation of radicals}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{R@b\lewis{2:6:,O}-[@a]-[@c]@d\lewis{2:6:,O}H}
%
\arrow{->[$h\nu$ (light) \quad or \quad $\triangle$ (heat)]}[0,3]
%
\chemnameinit{2pt}
\chemname{\chemfig{2\, \, R\lewis{0.2:6:,O}}}{}
%
\chemmove{
    \draw[myedge={right},red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=0pt](a).. controls +(90:4mm) and +(40:4mm)..(b);
    \draw[myedge={left},red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=0pt](c).. controls +(90:4mm) and +(140:4mm)..(d);
}
\schemestop
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{R-[0,1.5]\lewis{0.2:6:,O}\hspace{2pt}@e}
%
\chemfig{+\hspace{12pt}@f\hspace{12pt}}
%
\chemfig{H-[@g]-[@h]@i\lewis{0:2:6:,Br}}
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemfig{R-[0,1.5]\lewis{2:6:,O}H}
%
\+
%
\chemfig{\lewis{0.2:4:6:,Br}}
%
\chemmove{
    \draw[myedge={left},red,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=1pt](e.0).. controls +(90:8mm) and +(120:8mm)..(f);
    \draw[myedge={right},red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](g).. controls +(90:8mm) and +(60:8mm)..(f);
    \draw[myedge={left},red,shorten <=0pt,shorten >=1pt](h).. controls +(100:4mm) and +(140:6mm)..(i);
}
\schemestop
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(=-*6(-\chembelow{N}{H}-NH_2)=-=-)}\+\chemfig{(=[:-150]O)(-[:-30]R_2)-[2]-[:150]R_1}\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[\chemfig{H^+}]}\chemfig{*6(-=*5(-\chembelow{N}{H}-(-R_2)=(-R_1)-)-=-=)}
    \schemestop
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{C([3]-)([5]-)=[@{db,.5}]@{atoo}\charge{0=\|,-90=\|}{O}}\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<->}\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt=$\scriptstyle\oplus$}{C}([3]-)([5]-)-%
    \charge{0=\|,90=\|,-90=\|,45:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}}
    \schemestop
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{R-\charge{225:3pt=$\scriptstyle\oplus$}{N}([1]=[@{db}]@{atoo1}O)([7]-[@{sb}]@{atoo2}\charge{45=\|,-45=\|,-135=\|,45:5pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})}\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<->}\chemfig{R-\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\oplus$}{N}([1]-\charge{90:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O})([7]=O)}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{\draw[shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt](db) ..controls +(120:5mm) and +(120:7mm)..(atoo1);\draw[shorten <=3pt, shorten >=2pt](atoo2) ..controls +(225:10mm) and +(225:10mm)..(sb);}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]